# Lag spikes in Champion Selection

Tags: league-of-legends

Since the new client, I have huge lag spikes playing LoL. The weird thing is that I only got those spikes in Champion Selection.

It take ages to pick the champion I want to ban, ages to pick the champion I want to play. Sometimes I can't even change my masteries, my runes and the spells due to this lag.

If me and another player want to ban a champion, but he does it first, due to this huge lag spikes I don't have time to ban another champion and that results in dodging queue. It looks like the game freezes only in champion selection.

**UPDATE**: This happens to me too in the score's board after the game. It takes me ages to get the new honor page and then more a huge of time to get to the score's board

Is there any way to fix this huge lag spikes besides buying a new PC? I read in Riot's boards to change to legacy client, but those threads were old and nowadays there is no legacy client.

Comment: There is a checkbox to ignore the banning phase. So if you see that someone picked the same champ you wanted to ban and you'll get a queue dodge, immediately select it

Comment: the problem is: sometimes when I see that the champ is already banned is too late to pick another one. but I ll try that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling "Low Spec Mode"? You can enable this in the client settings box. You can also try this fix that someone suggested on the forums ([Source](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/XEgM8bVl-new-client-lag?comment=000e))

[image: Task Manager]

1. Open Task Manager
2. Right Click these programs

   - LeagueClient.exe
   - LeagueClientUx.exe
   - LeagueClientUxRender.exe
   - LeagueClientUxREnder.exe

Change Affinity to only CPU1 and CPU2